# How do I IIS redirect on a different port for tortoise svn

Tags: svn, redirect, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I installed VisualSVN Server on port 8080. So I can access it with `http://www.example.com:8080` and everything works fine.

I now want to access the svn using `http://svn.example.com` instead of using port 8080. So I created a HTTP Redirect in IIS 7 for site `svn.example.com` (which is on port 80) to `http://www.example.com:8080` (using permanent redirect).

This is working when I access the svn via a browser, however from within TortoiseSVN when I do Repository Browser, I see the following message:

**Repository moved permanently to.... Please Relocate**

Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The way I interpret the message you're getting is that the permanent redirect is telling Tortoise SVN that it needs to go to a different location to find the SVN server. Therefore, the client is telling you, as the user that you should update the configuration of your client repository. I suspect you need a proxy of some sort instead.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion does not handle redirects. Instead it errors out and tells you to relocate the working copy to the new url so no redirection is needed.

Comment: It is probably the client (in this case tortoisesvn), because I can see the repository via web browser just fine.

Comment: As I said: *Subversion* doesn't handle redirects. Your browser does.
It's not just TortoiseSVN that doesn't handle redirects, it's *all* svn clients.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure you are aware of this: 'relocate' is actually a Subversion command :-)

So

> Any ideas how to do this correctly?

- Right-click on the folder where you checked out (i.e. the working copy),
- click 'Relocate...',
- in the pop-up enter the new URL (i.e. replace http://www.mysite.com:8080 with http://svn.mysite.com) and
- click 'Ok'.

Comment: Tried Relocate and it did not work! forgot the error message that svn gave. So I am using the 8080 port for now and still looking for a solutions